# Why i can't access the properties of an object that came from props in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-props

So i have a class that receive an array with two objects in it as props.

If i console log it here, i can see that i have the value received
[image]

[image]

So the values are here. After that i'm trying to get just one of this objects that i need into the "currentCar" variable, as you can see. That works as well, i'm getting an array with just an element in there.

When i'm trying to send this "currentCar" variable as a prop to the EditCarComponent things change.

In my EditCarComponent i can do this and its fine:

[image]

It displays this:

[image]

As it should, i guess. But i soon as i try to do something like this:

[image]

I get :"TypeError: Cannot read property 'carName' of undefined"

And i don't really know what's the problem, and why i can't access the properties of that object that is CLEARLY there ??

Comment: in your first example you say this.props.cars and on the other you declare it as props.car[0] shouldn't be props.cars[0] ?

Comment: please share the code as text

Comment: It shouldn't be props.car[0], because i send it to that component as  car = {currentCar}, not  cars = {currentCar} ?

Comment: maybe the data is not accesible at the time you try to call it.

Comment: But then why ```console.log(props.car)``` works, and shows the object, but ```console.log(props.car.carName)``` its not working, it says that the object is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are using Array.filter instead Array.find, filter returns all the items in the array that match the condition in a new array, while find will get you the first item that match the condition, so if you want to get one result use the Array.find method instead.

```
const currentCar = this.props.cars.find((car) => car.carId === currentId)
```

Comment: I did that, thanks. Now my "currentCar" is actually just the one object i wanted, instead of the array. But i'm still passing it as ```car = {currentCar}``` to the other component and when i'm trying to acces some of its properties by ```props.car.carName``` let's say it says that is undefined, as before. But just ```props.car``` its not, its the whole object

Comment: So ```console.log(props.car)``` works, and shows the object, but ```console.log(props.car.carName)``` its not working, it says that the object is undefined

Comment: Can you post both console log in the question please? Because the object might have the field empty but I want to double check

Comment: I think you have an id that is not in the array, so the find returns undefined, remove the console log and try this     return props.car && (// your jsx code).  This will ensure that you only render the component if the car was found

Comment: I have tried to ```console.log(currentCar)``` right before i send it as props to the other component and it have a value. Its the object returned from the find. So i don't really think that's the problem.

Comment: hmm the error is telling that the car value is undefined so I'm pretty sure that's the case, because you only get undefined in the find method if your condition was not found at all.

Comment: But i don't get the undefined error there, i get it when i'm trying to use the props that i'm sending to the other component. So i exit the "find" with a valid object, and i pass it to the other component by props. The error happens when i'm trying to access one of its properties in the other component. Or, what i'm not understanding here ??